# Java URL encoding of a date (ZULU format)

Tags: java, encoding, timestamp, format

Say I have a url:

```
https://example/dateParam/
```

and I have a date value (ZULU format) entered by the user such as:

> 2016-07-20 13:10:04 +0300.

I want the result to be a properly encoded URL:

```
https://example/dateParam/2016-07-20%2013%3A10%3A04%20%2B0300
```

When I tried to do:

```
String dateParam = "2016-07-20 13:10:04 +0300";
String encodedParam = URLEncoder.encode(dateParam, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(encodedParam);
```

I get the following result:

> 2016-07-20+13%3A10%3A04+%2B0300

For the spaces I need %20 insteadof +. 
What's the best way to achieve this? I tried URLEncoder and creating URI/URL objects but none of them come out quite right.

Comment: How is the result you have not quite right? because the "+" is not being encoded?

Comment: As an aside, I don’t think there’s such a thing as a Zulu format, at least I haven’t heard about it. There’s a “Zulu time zone” with an offset of +00:00 (different from your +03:00).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest simplifying the problem to use a standard format like `20180906T223329Z`.

Parse your input string as [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html). Search Stack Overflow, as this has been covered many times already.

Adjust the [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) to zero, to [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) itself.

```
OffsetDateTime odtUtc = odt.withOffsetSameInstant( ZoneOffSet.UTC ) ;
```

Then create text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The “basic” versions of these formats minimize the use of delimiters. The `T` separates the years-months-days from the hours-minutes-seconds. The `Z` on the end means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), and is pronounced “Zulu”. Example:

> 20180906T223329Z

Use `DateTimeFormatter` class to generate a String.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatterofPattern( "uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmssX" ) ;
String output = odtUtc.format( f ) ;
```

Lastly, run that output through your URL encoder.